# subtract multiple columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, subtraction

I have two dataframes:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [7,8, 2], 'b': [6, 6, 11], 'c': [4, 8, 6]})
df_1
```

[image: df_1]

and

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'d' : [8, 4, 12], 'e': [16, 2, 1], 'f': [9, 3, 4]})
df_2
```

[image: df_2]

My goal is something like:

[image: expected output]

In a way that 'in one shot' I can subtract each column multiple times.

I'm trying `for` loop but I´m stuck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subtract them as numpy arrays (using `.values`) and then put the result in a dataframe:

```
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(df_1.values - df_2.values, columns=list('xyz'))

#     x   y  z
# 0  -1 -10 -5
# 1   4   4  5
# 2 -10  10  2
```

Or rename `df_1.columns` and `df_2.columns` to `['x','y','z']` and you can subtract them directly:

```py
df_1.columns = df_2.columns = list('xyz')
df_3 = df_1 - df_2

#     x   y  z
# 0  -1 -10 -5
# 1   4   4  5
# 2 -10  10  2
```